# How do I avoid allocations in Iterator::flat_map?

Tags: rust, iterator, declarative

I have a `Vec` of integers and I want to create a new `Vec` which contains those integers and squares of those integers. I could do this imperatively:

```rust
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut new_v = Vec::new(); // new instead of with_capacity for simplicity sake.
for &x in v.iter() {
    new_v.push(x);
    new_v.push(x * x);
}
println!("{:?}", new_v);
```

but I want to use iterators. I came up with this code:

```rust
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let new_v: Vec<_> = v.iter()
    .flat_map(|&x| vec![x, x * x])
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", new_v);
```

but it allocates an intermediate `Vec` in the `flat_map` function.

How to use `flat_map` without allocations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`ArrayVec`](https://docs.rs/arrayvec/0.5.1/arrayvec/struct.ArrayVec.html) for this.

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let new_v: Vec<_> = v.iter()
    .flat_map(|&x| ArrayVec::from([x, x * x]))
    .collect();
```

Making arrays be by-value iterators, so that you wouldn't need `ArrayVec` has been discussed, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25725 and the linked PRs.

Answer (score 4):

As of Rust 1.53.0, this can be written with just the array literal:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let new_v: Vec<_> = v.iter()
    .flat_map(|&x| [x, x * x])
    .collect();
```

Rust 1.53.0 implements [IntoIterator for arrays](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/06/17/Rust-1.53.0.html#intoiterator-for-arrays), so the `vec![]` and workarounds in previous solutions are no longer needed. This works on all editions.

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.51.0, the struct `core::array::IntoIter` has been stabilized. You can use it like this:

```
use core::array;

let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let new_v: Vec<_> = v.iter()
    .flat_map(|&x| array::IntoIter::new([x, x * x]))
    .collect();
```

The documentation warns that this may be deprecated in the future when `IntoIterator` is implemented for arrays, but currently it's the easiest way to do this.

Comment: To be clear, the "this" that may be deprecated is creation with the `new` function, not `array::IntoIter` itself. If arrays ever do get `IntoIterator`, you'll be able to just write `flat_map(|&x| [x, x * x])`.

Answer (score 2):

If your iterator is small and you don't want any external dependencies, a short iterator can be constructed from [`std::iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/fn.once.html) and [`std::iter::Iterator::chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain). For example,

```
use std::iter;

let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let new_v: Vec<_> = v
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|&x| iter::once(x).chain(iter::once(x * x)))
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", new_v);
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e429f28f6f086d7d0d964ef2f3493705)

This could be made into a macro, though be aware that using this for too many elements may cause the recursion limit to be reached. If you're making an iterator for more than a few dozen elements, it's probably not too bad to have an allocation. If you really need the slight increase in performance, nnnmmm's solution is probably better.

```
macro_rules! small_iter {
    () => { std::iter::empty() };
    ($x: expr) => {
        std::iter::once($x)
    };
    ($x: expr, $($y: tt)*) => {
        std::iter::once($x).chain(small_iter!($($y)*))
    };
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let new_v: Vec<_> = v
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|&x| small_iter!(x, x * x))
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", new_v);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe3aae0efa58097d02989c94b041e30b)